# asmx implementing a "fire and forget" attribute

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, async-await

I have a legacy webservice (asmx) that implements a [SoapDocumentMethod(OneWay = true)] attribute. The service runs a long time running process. As the client does not wait for the answer, what happens to the thread that is running the process on the server ? While the process is running, does that mean that some ressources of the webservice are locked ? Do I need async/await calls on the service to scale and restore some availability ?